# How to use decimal in x64dbg calculator?

Tags: x64dbg, hexadecimal

The x64dbg calculator can evaluate hex expressions.

[image]

Is there a syntax to calculate the sum of a hex value and a decimal value? For the example in the snapshot, is it possible to treat `10` as a decimal? The expected result is `939936F59A`. If it can't, what's the most convenient tool to do this kind of calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

For *decimal* numbers, use the syntax *with the period just **before*** the number, e.g. `.10`:

[image]

Particularly, in your case you will obtain exactly what you wanted (I omitted leading zeroes):

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works! How did you find it? The documentation is basically empty!

Comment: I didn't search for it, I already read the complete doc.:-)  You're right, it is spare enough. Here is the link to the relevant part: [Numbers](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/Input.html#numbers). I quote from it: “All numbers are interpreted as hex by default! If you want to be sure, you can x or 0x as a prefix. Decimal numbers can be used by prefixing the number with a dot: `.123=7B`.”